# Looking for a particular type of smart light switch

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I have 4 regular white light switches in a 4-gang box. I want to replace one switch with a Google Nest compatible smart light switch with the following goals:

1. Be able to turn the front and back floodlights quickly using Google Nest (2 switches, different sides of the house).
2. Be able to manually switch the individual lights.
3. Have it look good with the current 4-gang switch plates (preferably identical to the current toggle awitches).

I have tried searching but can only find switches that look different than the one it will replace. Any ideas?

Comment: "exactly" is going to be tough, because at a minimum there will typically be some indicator lights to show WiFi connection status.

Comment: This is not a "shop for me" site, so our ability to help is limited. Also, the big blocky Decora style is fashionable these days, the old slot/toggle switches are "outré".

Comment: Not looking for anyone to do any searching that I can do. I've searched a but can't find anything and was hoping someone might know what direction to point me in. While I appreciate fashion tips, that was not part of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "want to replace one switch" but also "2 switches, different sides" and "switch the individual lights"?   It is hard to understand what you want to change and how you want it to work.   As general guidance, there are lots of Wifi and Z-Wave switches that can replace most existing ones ... two way, three way, dimming, paddle, toggle, etc etc.  If you can describe what you want we can probably give some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an X-Y problem. As in, you are probably not the typical Google Nest (or similar) convenience user but rather have a specific *goal* in mind, so that "exactly the same as the other switches" is not a matter of aesthetics but rather to hide the fact that it is a remotely controllable switch. My guess:

- You have a light that is often left on for extended periods of time and you would like to be able to turn it off remotely without the usual users (teenage kids?) knowing that you can control it remotely.

But there are some other scenarios I can think of that are entirely different.

I suspect *any* such switch will have, at a minimum, some indicator lights to show WiFi/connectivity status. The only *totally normal looking* method I can think of would require quite a bit of work:

- Replace this switch with a *3-way* switch.
- Add a new, Google Nest compatible switch someplace else. *Make sure it can handle a normal 3-way switch, some can, some can't (and require their own special switches for the other part of a 3-way switch circuit).*
- Run the proper cable - likely 4-wire (plus ground) - hot, neutral, 2 travelers - between the two switches.

Now you'd have to do the work when the parties you are concerned about are not home (as opposed to a straight dumb/smart switch replacement which you might be able to do in 15 minutes) and come up with an explanation for the new switch - but if you can hide it in a closet then maybe nobody will notice.

The 3-way switch solution does have one catch: The switch will alternate between "up = on/down = off" and "up = off/down = on" each time you remotely turn it on or off. Very noticeable with standard toggle switches. Less noticeable with Decora style.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took for the answer. Here's what I would like to acheive: 1. Be able to turn the front and back floodlights quickly (2 switches, different sides of the house) and 2. Be able to manually switch the lights and 3. Have it look good with the current 4-gang switch plates. Thanks for the good questions to clarify.

Comment: Yes, the "hidden second 3-way" solution is *so fetch*.  Or if your system is already 3-way, "third hidden 3-way with one of the switches converted to plain 4-way".

Comment: Put that in the original question, @RetiredATC so _everyone_ will know what the real question is.

Comment: Good suggestion @FreeMan. Done.

Answer (score 2):

There is a class of smart switches that look similar to toggle switches, but because smart switches don't move the hardware toggle when they're flipped via "smarts" the toggle sits in the middle position.

I believe they can be pushed in either direction to physically toggle the light on or off; but to more closely imitate a toggle they might only allow an upward push to turn the light on, down to turn it off (and a push in the wrong direction would do nothing).

As Harper said in a comment, Decora smart switches are much more common and useful, since they can more readily imitate a button that will change the light state. The only reason to use these "toggle-ish" smart switches is to look kind of like a toggle.

Here's an example I found via Lowe's (no endorsement implied, I would actually use a different brand and supplier personally).

[image]

Comment: That's as close as I have seen. I'm trying to replace 1 switch in each of 2 4-switch gangs. This looks like it will work, now I need to see if it will fit in the switch plates. Thank you.